# What is $(x+1)^4$ in $GF(3)[x]^*_{x^2+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the field $GF(3)[x]^*_{x^2+1}$. My textbook says that $(x+1)^4 = 2$ in this field, but i don't understand how mulitplication works in this field

With $GF(3)[x]^*_{x^2+1} = \{  a(x) \in GF(3)[x]_{x^2+1} \ | gcd(a(x),x^2+1= 1 \}$

Comment: What does the $^*$ mean?

Comment: The notation is, IMHO, non-standard, I would write this ring as $GF(3)[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ (it's a field actually). But anyway, you are expected to give the remainder of a polynomial division by $x^2+1$. Remember that in the quotient ring $x^2+1$ *and all its polynomial multiples* become equated with zero. So
$$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=2x+1\cdot(x^2+1)\equiv 2x\pmod{x^2+1}.$$
Now you should be able to do your exercise starting with $(x+1)^4=((x+1)^2)^2\equiv(2x)^2=\cdots$. Remember that you are to also reduce *coefficient* (but not exponents) modulo three, because in $GF(3)$ we have $3=0$.

Comment: Also, Welcome to MSE! Please also spend a while studying [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Some users are known to be rather unforgiving about shortcomings in questions that look like homework assignments. If you can use the hints/pointers in my first comment as means for either improving the question and/or answering it yourself, I will be  that much happier.

Comment: @Arthur i added the meaning of this notation

Comment: That's not a field. Without the $^*$ it's a field, but with it you don't have a $0$, so it's just a group under multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean what I would call $\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$, i.e. take a polynomial ring over the field of three elements, and divide out by the ideal generated by $x^2+1$, then this is a field with nine elements:
$$\begin{matrix}
0&1&2\\x&x+1&x+2\\2x&2x+1&2x+2\end{matrix}
$$
and multiplication is simple: First you multiply two elements as you would any polynomial. Then you take any $x^2$ you see, and you swap it out with $2$ (note: $x^2+1 = 0$ means $x^2=2$ in $\Bbb F_3$, so $x^2$ is, in the quotient ring, literally the same as $2$).

For instance, we have
$$
(2x+1)\cdot (x+2) = 2x^2 + 2x + 2\\
= 2\cdot 2 + 2x + 2 = 2x
$$
In your example, using the binomial theorem (in $\Bbb F_3$ we have $\binom41 = 1$ and $\binom42 = 0$), we get
$$
(x + 1)^4 = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1\\
= (x^2)^2 + x^2\cdot x + x + 1\\
= 2^2 + 2x + x + 1\\
= 2
$$

Comment: As an aside, I have no idea why teachers and books aren't using this approach to introduce complex numbers (i.e. highlight $i^2 = -1$ rather than $i = \sqrt{-1}$).